# How to do a conditional generic type that has a value when it is undefined but not when it is undefined AND another thing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type where I want to define an object key as optional with `any` If I do not give any value

```
type OptionalData<T> = T extends undefined ? { data?: any } : { data: T };

export type DataObject<T = any> = {
  item?: string | null;
} & OptionalData<T>;
```

It works ok until I set my generic as `something | undefined`

```
const data: DataObject<string | undefined> = { data: true }; // WRONG!
const data2: DataObject<string | number> = { data: true }; // CORRECT
```

since my generic can also extend `undefined` I get data as optional `any`

[image: ipt]

Is there a way to say "it is just optional `any` when it can JUST extend `undefined`" or so?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwCJuGgPACoB8UAvFIVBAB7AQoAmAzlAK5MQBmCKEjUAPxQA3lEa40ggFxQ0KEFAC+UWWIl5ZVJQG4AUHtpgkAJ2BRQkKDjwwARgCsIAY2BFychaQoi9UKAj0ALYyUMzAJrwA5lAAPlAobBgY+ioAZLDwyOjYkkTE+gbOqOHikrI2aPZOrvjhkSgx8RyM3Lz83qJlmhYmbNC6UAD0Q1AA6gBKMAByAOIAhHrFKKUaaABMFZLVLm710XEJbEF2ECad6uW9-co6w6MAwjATEwCiD4R6QA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem

You have these types:

```
type OptionalData<T> = T extends undefined ? { data?: any } : { data: T };

export type DataObject<T = any> = {
  item?: string | null;
} & OptionalData<T>;
```

When you type a variable as `DataObject` with the type parameter being a union of a type (such as `string`) and `undefined` you expect the data property to be typed as the union type however it is typed as `any`:

```
const data: DataObject<string | undefined> = { data: ... }

// data.data should be typed as `string | undefined` however
// data.data is typed as `any`
```

### What is happening?

TypeScript's documentation for conditional types is useful here. It reads:

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C for T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.

– [Documentation on distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

So in your case it resolves to

```
| (string extends undefined ? { data?: any } : { data: T })
| (undefined extends undefined ? { data?: any } : { data: T })
```

The first conditional resolves to `{ data: T }` and the second resolves to `{ data?: any }`. I believe union types will resolve to the type that is the most generic so the type is eventually `{ data?: any }`.

## Solution

Here's `OptionalData` updated so that it works as expected:

```
type OptionalData<T> = [T] extends [undefined] ? { data?: any } : { data: T };
```

We just wrapped `T` and `undefined` with square brackets (`[]`), turning them into tuples (or technically monuple because it's only got one element). Here's the [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwCJuGgPACoB8UAvFANqEC6UEAHsBCgCYDOVArmxAGYIUEVnQD8UAN5RWuNKIBcUNChBQAvlEVSZeRYXUBuAFBHGYJACdgUUJCg48MAEYArCAGNgRckpWkKEkZQUAjMALYKUOzAFoIA5lAAPlAoXBgYxhoAZLDwyOjYskTExibuqNHSsooOaM5unvjRsSgJyTys-ILC-pJVujYWXNBqBlAA9ONQAOoASjAAcgDiAIRG5SiVOmgATDWy9R5ezfFJKVxhThAWvdrVg8OGE1MAwjCzswCiL4RGQA).

### Why does this work?

Let's look back at the documentation for conditional types again, with some added emphasis on the important parts:

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a **naked type** parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are **automatically distributed over union types** during instantiation.

As we turned those naked types to tuples they are not naked anymore. And because they are no longer naked they are no longer distributed.