# Conditional return type extending undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm in the process of creating an utility for handling API responses where I would like to avoid consumers having to check for undefined when specifying a generic type:

```js
export async function createAPIResponse<T = undefined>(
    request: Request,
    response: Response
): Promise<T extends undefined ? undefined : T> {
    if (response.status === 204) {
        return;
    }

    if (!response.ok) {
        try {
            throw new APIError(request, response, await response.json());
        } catch {
            throw new HTTPError(request, response);
        }
    }

    return response.json();
}
```

TypeScript gives me the following error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends undefined ? undefined : T'. ts(2322)

My goal is being able to utilize the function like this:

```js
// No response expected and no generic passed to function
try {
    await createAPIResponse(putRequest, responseWithStatus204AndNoBody);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}

// Response of type SomeType expected
try {
    const jsonData = await createAPIResponse<SomeType>(getRequest, responseWithStatus200AndJSONBody);
    console.log(jsonData);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

I've looked around for some possible solutions (e.g. [How to do a conditional generic type that has a value when it is undefined but not when it is undefined AND another thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896115/how-to-do-a-conditional-generic-type-that-has-a-value-when-it-is-undefined-but-n)) but I've yet to find one that doesn't produce an error.

Comment: You will need a type assertion the implementation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, could you provide an example?

Comment: He means something like: obj as ExpectedType. Anyway, why don't you just to use T=unknown and return Promise<T>?

Comment: @tokland declaring T = unknown still gives me the same original 2322 error when attempting to return from within the status conditional (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjTgymARmAEEAFASQCVglI0lgAeAFTgF44+ANZoIAdzQA+ABQAoOIrgU2JTgC44LVR2ByAlJrpQIAW0KdeUuAG8FSgPQO4AOQhkS1NDHuLC2OBkVdk4AOiQYKlwkAX5BACYABgAWfVtfJUUKGFwoNABuDIBfOQz-QIBCYLVgUIhhNLtMzJgACxNxODRgToBRKBMoINYQ2oiopB5QGH1CzJKM7NzSat1QgCskEhlZuSKgA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm satisfied with the solution as suggested by [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618632/conditional-return-type-extending-undefined?noredirect=1#comment124837955_70618632) which I ended up implementing as follows:

```js
type OptionalReturn<T> = T extends undefined ? void : T;

export async function createAPIResponse<T = undefined>(
    request: Request,
    response: Response
): Promise<OptionalReturn<T>> {
    // No content
    if (response.status === 204) {
        return undefined as OptionalReturn<T>;
    }
    
    ...
}
```